# Space Centurions V

Tags: online-resources, games, space-centurions-v

About 1977 some friends and I played a game called ‘Space Centurions V’ (5). It was a play by mail game, colonizing and conquering planets.

I am inventing a similar game and wonder if anyone has a copy of the old rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't able to find *Space Centurions V*, but I was able to find *[Space Centurions X](https://archive.org/details/SpaceCenturionsX/mode/2up?q=space+centurions)* and *Space Centurions XII* in The Internet Archive.

The game was created by Ivan Travnicek. According to [an archived thread](https://rec.games.board.narkive.com/xzukgnUY/space-games-old-space-or-star-empire-star-centurion), *Space Centurions V* appeared in the winter 1972 issue of *The Spartan*, the magazine of the Spartan International Competition League.

Comment: There may be author contact info at https://spaceship.brainiac.com/spacecompany9.html#travnicek

Comment: I read the introduction to the document you sent, and SC5 was in there. Not the rules, unfortunately, but they listed it as a development that lead to SC 10. Thanks much.

Comment: I sent an email to Ivan from the contact details I linked above. We'll see if anything comes of it.